# Loading environment variables with dotenv still returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm at a loss here. My `.env` file is in my root directory, as instructed. I've tried this by way of both `require('dotenv').config()` and `import dotenv from 'dotenv'`, followed by `dotenv.config()`. I've tried passing config an absolute path, as you will see. Trying to console log the environment variables always returns undefined. I tried checking for `dotenv.error`, as you will also see, and the condition doesn't trigger.

All I see is undefined. It's as if my `.env` file doesn't even exist.

Here is my code in its current state. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import multer from "multer";
import AWS, { PutObjectCommandOutput, S3, S3ClientConfig } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { createReadStream } from "fs";
import path from 'path';

const dotenvAbsolutePath = path.join(__dirname, '.env')

const app = express();
const port = 5000;
// require('dotenv').config();
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({
  path: dotenvAbsolutePath,
});
if (dotenv.error) {
  console.log(`DOTENV ERROR: ${dotenv.error.message}`);
  throw dotenv.error;
}

const keys = {
  key: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secret: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION
};
console.log(dotenv);

const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({ destination: "./tmp" }),
});

const s3 = new S3({
  credentials: { accessKeyId: keys.key!, secretAccessKey: keys.secret! },
  region: keys.region!
});

app.use(cors());

app.post("/", upload.single("pdf_upload"), async (req, res) => {
  let fileName: string | undefined;
  // let fileBuffer: Buffer | undefined;
  let uploadResponse: PutObjectCommandOutput | undefined;

  if (req.file) {
    fileName = req.file.originalname;
    // fileBuffer = req.file.buffer
    console.log("HTTP Request Received");
    const fileReadStream = createReadStream(req.file!.path).on(
      "ready",
      async () => {
        try {
          console.log("Stream is Readable");
          console.log(fileReadStream.bytesRead);
          uploadResponse = await s3.putObject({
            Bucket: "fiberpunch-test",
            Key: fileName,
            Body: fileReadStream,
          });
          res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          res
            .send({ file: { ETag: uploadResponse.ETag, Key: fileName } })
            .status(200);
        } catch (err: any) {
          console.log("Upload Error: ", err.message);
          res.sendStatus(500);
          console.log(fileReadStream.bytesRead);
        }
      }
    );
  }
});

try {
  app.listen(port);
  console.log(`listening at port ${port}`);
} catch (err) {
  console.log("ERROR SETTING UP SERVER");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. First of all, I was working in typescript and forgot to compile. Second, the absolute path to the .env file was incorrect. After I did that, the environmental variable pull just fine.

I'm running into a new error, though:

```
Upload Error:  The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
```

I'll post another question if I can't figure this one out. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `process.env` to access your env variables. Try logging `process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`

Comment: That's actually what I was originally doing. First I tried accessing them directly. Then storing them to variables. Then storing them to an array. Then storing them to an object. All returned undefined.

Comment: Do you have screenshots or code somewhere that I can look at? Can you also verify if the issue is specific to that project only?

Comment: All of my code is above. That's the entire back end for this project so far.

Comment: But it does seem to be specific to this project. I created a test project with only a package.json, .env, and index.js. Used dotenv with a test variable in this same manner, and it returned the value just fine. So I'm not sure what's causing this.

Comment: Comment out everything unnecessary :D.

Answer (score 0):

If you use AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in your .env file, you don't have to use them again to create a S3 object. AWS automatically recognizes these keys and uses them for S3 object creation.
You only need region to create a S3 object.

```js
const s3 = new S3({
  region: 'your region'
});
```